# scipy definitely installed but will not import

Tags: python, scipy, pip

I am trying to install scipy for python 3.7 and it seems to install correctly, I have been installing it through pip using the command:

```
python -m pip install scipy
```

The installer says that it has successfully installed scipy-1.2.1 , however, when I try to use it in the console or any IDE it claims that scipy does not contain the attribute

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'integrate'
```

Please help.

Comment: How do you try to import scipy exactly?

Comment: execute `python --version` and `pip --version` ...and let us see

Comment: python --version
Python 3.7.2                                                                                                                                 python -m pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: And i tried to import scipy using the command above, the files were created and are in the same place as the other installed libraries

Comment: In your script are you using `import scipy` or `from scipy import *` ?

Comment: I have tried from scipy import * and import scipy as sp

Comment: Please show the *exact* code that you tried to run.  If you use `import scipy`, and then try to use `scipy.integrate`, it won't work.  You must explicitly import the `integrate` subpackage, e.g. `import scipy.integrate`.  (If that turns out to be the problem, then this question is a duplicate--many times over!  It's definitely a surprise for many first-time users of scipy.)

Comment: Yes that is the solution thank you v. much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supposes you're using Windows, the short way to solve this and possible future problems is to uninstall your present python version and install `Anaconda`. With Anaconda package you get `scipy`, `numpy`, `matplotlib` and some others libraries for Python. Try it!

Comment: I have just done that and it is still not working, It still still says that all of the functions I try to use from scipy are not defined.

Comment: Are you selecting properly the python version in your IDE ?

Comment: I am mostly sure and I have tried on multiple IDEs

Comment: Don't worry it was an issue with my code rather than anything else it seems. Thank you